# Web api with Automapper gives Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, automapper

I'm Using Web api and I am trying to map the Model to the View Model and vice versa. but I am getting an error message that states that

```
Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping
```

I have the following layers:

- DAL Layer (Class Library project) here I'm using Auto mapper
- BLL Layer (Class Library project)
- Service Layer (Web Api project)

and here is my code:

Initialize Class:

```
 public class DomainToViewModelMap : AutoMapper.Profile
    {
        public override string ProfileName
        {
            get { return "ViewModelToDomainMappings"; }
        }
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<Notification, NotificationModel>();
            });
        }
    }
    public class ViewModelToDomainMap : AutoMapper.Profile
    {
        public override string ProfileName
        {
            get { return "ViewModelToDomainMappings"; }
        }
        protected override void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.CreateMap<NotificationModel, Notification>();
            });
        }
    }
    public class AutoMapperConfigurationTest
    {
        public static void Configure()
        {
            Mapper.Initialize(x =>
            {
                x.AddProfile<DomainToViewModelMap>();
                x.AddProfile<ViewModelToDomainMap>();
            });
        }
    }
```

And I am calling it from Application_Start in Global.asax:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AutoMapperConfigurationTest.Configure();
    }
```

DAL Layer:

```
    public static NotificationModel GetByID(int ID)
    {
            using (Data.ZajelEntities db = new Data.ZajelEntities())
            {
                var notification = db.Notifications.Find(ID);
                if (notification != null)
                {
                    return Mapper.Map<Notification, NotificationModel>(notification);
                }
            }

        return null;
    }
```

I know that this issue related to initialization but i am sure the initialization code run through Global.asax of web api

What is missing ?

Comment: Where that error occurs?

Comment: as I mentioned above when I map from model to the View Model. I got an exception state that: Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the base CreateMap method in your Profile, not Mapper.Initialize. Mapper.Initialize should be called once per AppDomain.